# Where are "Debug Dump Files" located in windows?

Tags: windows, log-files, diskmanagement, dump, cleanup

Windows has a tool called "**Disk Cleanup**" (German: Datenträgerbereinigung).
There it lists "**Debug Dump Files**" which can be deleted.
Unfortunately it doesn't tell me which files are meant. It can't be only the folder `C:\Windows\Minidump` because in my case it tells me that it would delete 5.65 GB, but the Minidump Folder only contains some KB.

Where are the files located which will be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I analyzed the file system during deletion process.
Basically the Folder `C:\Windows\Minidump` was not touched at all.
It deleted the file `C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP` and freed up several Gigabyte.

Answer (score 0):

Debug dumps (process dumps) are not the same as memory.dmp which is a full write out of the memory contents at a given time. If you have 8GB of memory with a swap file of similar size, the . memory.dmp will be a few gigs as stated.

Comment: I imagine that from Microsoft's perspective the kernel memory dumps are debug dumps too; they get used to debug Windows. :-)